# extract listbox items in tkinter - python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

list_box = Listbox(root, selectmode = "multiple")
for i in range(10):
    list_box.insert(i, str(i) + "item" )

list_box.pack()

mainloop()
```

How can I extract the selected items?

I tried `list_box.get(list_box.curselection()[0])` but always get a `TclError: invalid command name` error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to provide the full code, notably, the exact place where you're trying to extract the selected items.

I added some code to do it in a button, and it seems to work fine here:

[image: Example screenshot]

The code is your code, I only added this just before the call to `mainloop()`:

```
# ... your code here ...
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmsg
def clicked():
    selected = [list_box.get(pos) for pos in list_box.curselection()]
    tkmsg.showinfo(title='Selected', 
        message='Items selected: {}'.format(', '.join(selected)))
Button(root, text='Go!', command=clicked).pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks @nosklo. The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to store the selected items in a variable in order to use it later in my program. Instead of showing it on the screen with tkmsg is there a way to put the selected items in a variable?

Comment: sure! in my example they are being stored in the `selected` variable, just before being displayed...

Comment: @HappyPy I changed the answer slightly so that `selected` is now a variable containing the list of the selected items.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @nosklo. But how do you exactly access `selected` outside the `clicked` function then? Do you mean I should make `selected` global?

Comment: @HappyPy That is a different problem, the usual approach is to use classes, then you can put `selected` in a instance attribute. But `global` would work too - just remember that you can only access the variable after the user has clicked in the button.